# Can I create a list from groupby with only items that have equal value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df.groupby(['foo'])[['bar']].count()
```

[image]

This is what I get from applying this groupby.
What I want to be able to do is to only keep item 3 and 4 as they are the only ones that have an equal amount of 'bar'. Is there a way I can store the string 'Item3' and 'Item4' into a list? I apologize for the terrible format, I am new to this.

Comment: item3? item4? equal amount of bar? Please give an example. Not an external image.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding `duplicated` and then `.index.tolist()` after `groupby`

```
df.groupby(['foo'])[['bar']].count().duplicated(keep=False).index.tolist()
Out[320]: ['ITEM3', 'ITEM4']
```